# How to make interval between date in xaxis flot jquery graph

Tags: jquery, flot

This is my code:

```
var xaxisdata = xaxis;
var data1=yaxis;
var data2 = yaxis2;

var dataset = [
    {
       label:cond[1],
        data: yaxis,
        yaxis: 1,
        color: "#990099",
        points: { symbol: "circle", fillColor: "#990099", show: false },
        lines: {show:true }
    },
    {
        label:cond[2],
        data: data2,
        yaxis: 2,
        color: "#b7cb37",
        points: { symbol: "circle", fillColor: "#b7cb37", show: false },
        lines: { show: true }    
    },
];

var options = {
    xaxis: {
        ticks: xaxisdata,       
        // axisLabel: "2012",
        color: "#8b8b8b",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: false,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 9,
        // axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 10,
        minTickSize: 35,
    },    
    yaxes: [
        {
            position: "left",
            color: "#8b8b8b",
            min:minleft,max:maxleft,
            axisLabel: cond[1],
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 0
        },
        {
            position: "right",
            min:minright,max:maxright,
            color: "#8b8b8b",
            axisLabel: cond[2],
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding: 3
        },
    ],

    legend: {
        noColumns: 0,
        labelFormatter: function (label, series) {
            return "<font style=\"color:#999;\">" + label + "</font>";
        },            
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        backgroundOpacity: 0.9,
        labelBoxBorderColor: "#e5e5e5",
        position: "nw"
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: 0,
        mouseActiveRadius: 50,
        backgroundColor: { colors: ["#fff", "#fff"] },
        axisMargin: 20
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#flot-placeholder"), dataset, options);
    $("#flot-placeholder").UseTooltip();
});


});
```

I want to make interval between x-axis not all they are overlapping with each other. It contains date series data

```
0,2011-11-04,1,2011-11-04,2,2011-11-04,3,2011-12-16,4,2011-12-16,5,2011-12-16,6,2012-05-11,7,2012-05-11,8,2012-05-11,9,2012-07-13,10,2012-07-13,11,2012-07-13,12,2012-08-09,13,2012-08-09,14,2012-08-09,15,2012-08-31,16,2012-08-31,17,2012-08-31,18,2012-11-09,19,2012-11-09,20,2012-11-09,21,2013-02-08,22,2013-02-08,23,2013-02-08,24,2013-02-25,25,2013-02-25,26,2013-02-25,27,2013-08-09,28,2013-08-09,29,2013-08-09,30,2013-11-22,31,2013-11-22,32,2013-11-22,33,2014-05-05,34,2014-05-05,35,2014-05-05,36,2014-06-27,37,2014-06-27,38,2014-06-27
```

I want to make interval between this date range like 5 months gap or year gap. Is there any way to do this? I have tried `minTIckSize`, but it seems not to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can define,

```
mode: time,
tickSize: [1, "day"] // show ticks at an interval of 1 day
```

**tickSize:**

> Another option is to skip the rounding part and directly set the tick
>   interval size with "tickSize". If you set it to 2, you'll get ticks at
>   2, 4, 6, etc. Alternatively, you can specify that you just don't want
>   ticks at a size less than a specific tick size with "minTickSize".
>   Note that for time series, the format is an array like [2, "month"],
>   see the next section.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/A24Vt/120/)**